# Flutter web - Setup Google Map and Marker does not update

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-markers, flutter-web, mobile-browser

Find the solution below, it took me a day to get this working.

Issue:

- Unable to load maps for the web
- Unable to update marker on the map on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Issue 1:

- add google_maps_flutter_web package to pubspec.yaml in addition to google_maps_flutter. No need to add imports in any files.
- Use Google Map Javascript Api Key or (might work) Map Api key from your Google Cloud Project. It requires a trial subscription atleast and the setup of a billing account.
- The Map should now be functioning even on mobile browser.

Issue 2:

- This GitHub issue solves this, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65255#issuecomment-737050548
- TL;DR? clear markers -> call setState -> Future delayed for 250ms -> add marker -> setState.

Comment: I've added those 2 packages but why do you say no need to import them? Mine has errors without import. I can't import them both and get them working on web.

Comment: From what I can remember, the google_maps_flutter_web package works in tandem with the stock package, like an extension. I tried around and figured out what works.